# What transistors can I use instead of BS170/2N7000, and what parameters to look at?

Tags: transistors

I'm following the below schematic for a tremolo guitar effects pedal. I'm trying to figure out how I can use any of the transistors that I have available (image further below) instead of the three listed, but have had a hard time understanding which values to compare in the data sheets.

What should I be looking at?

Schematic:

[image].

Available transistors:

[image]

Comment: None of these are going to be drop-in replacements for FETs. I recommend getting yourself a pack of assorted FETs if you're a hobbyist.

Comment: Thank you @Hearth! Just for my understanding, if the transistors I have are not FETs, what are they? Sorry if I am not knowledgeable enough, it was a long time since I studied electronics.

Comment: They're BJTs. FET stands for field-effect transistor, which includes both JFETs, junction field-effect transistors; and MOSFETS/MISFETS/IGFETs, metal-oxide-semiconducter/metal-insulator-semiconductor/insulated-gate field-effect transistors (the terms are mostly interchangeable). BJT stands for bipolar junction transistor, and they work on a completely different principle.

Comment: *Gen. purp. NPN* it says on your picture.

Comment: This is a slightly vague question because your goals and specifications are unclear. I advise you to understand what you really need. Do you want a faster response? Do you want a higher gain? Do you want something that consumes less power? etc. This is the sort of thing where you would review the specifications.

Comment: Thansistors you've got are PNP and NPN bipolar junction transistors. If you are going to build vintage audio circuits, definitely get some J201, because they used to be very popular in synths and effects. They are still available, I've recently got them from Mouser.

Comment: @KingDuken Thank you, this is why I wrote about my application, sorry if that was unclear: to make the schematic work. I should have written that changes to the sound are not too important.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hearth and @VolodymyrSmotesko , your answers were very helpful!

Comment: Q1 is stock item FET with many equivalents as a 5 Ohm switch +/-xx%, with 180 OHms to Q2 as a voltage divider to then modulate the pulse feedback to attenuate the peaks

Comment: Thank you @SunnyskyguyEE75 ! I'm searching for equivalents right now and having a hard time. What would you suggest I search for, an assorted pack of FETs? Such packs seem somewhat cryptic to an amateur like me -- is there a way to know which ones are "equivalent" from a list of "codes" e.g. BC636, GD241C, 2N1711, BC556B, BC549B, ...? These are all listed as NPN/PNP, does that mean that they are bipolar and not FETs and wouldn't work as Q1? I apologise for the extended question, I realise this might not be the best place.

Comment: Any large distributor has these parts I linked in stock  .. Avnet, Mouser, etc  Google search descriptions and shopping near you https://www.google.com/search?q=bs170&sxsrf=ACYBGNRlLjeKcWKec9tiT8cpxpJFtFYx6Q:1570723521164&source=lnms&tbm=shop

Comment: @Anna NPN and PNP are types of bipolar transistors. The 'equivalent' for FETs is N-channel and P-channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to re analyze the transistor amplifier sections, it would be best to use the transistors specified:

Q1: is an N-channel mosfet [BS170](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor-Fairchild/BS170?qs=FOlmdCx%252BAA0Q%252B3zvwxJUKQ%3D%3D) an NPN will not work in the place of it.

Q2: is a JFET MPF102 which is obsolete and you might want to use a [substitute](http://www.hawestv.com/amp_projects/fet_preamp/fet-mpf102-sub1.htm) if you can't find one.

Q3: is a 2N5088 which is an NPN transistor, with an hFE of 300 (and it's own gain curve), while you might be able to substitute a 2N3904, the circuit won't sound the same.